# Inductor magnetic field collapses during switching?

Tags: inductor, buck, switching-regulator, ripple

**SEE EDITS BELOW**

I'm running into some problems with my Buck converter design. During the switching period the inductors magnetic field seems to collapse, which generates some large voltage peaks. That's what I think is happening at least.

Some general specs of the converter are: (schematic attached as image below)

- AP64500
- Input Capacitor 2x10uF (one of them is in another part of the schematic)
- Output Capacitor 1x47uF
- Inductor 3.3uH
- Switching Frequency 500kHz
- Input voltage ~14.7V (lead acid battery), output 3.1V
- Specs are more or less copied from the recommended components, on page 14 of the datasheet https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP64500.pdf

As you can see in the image I have attached, there are some rather large peaks during the switching period, which I think originate from the Inductors magnetic field collapsing. The thing is, I don't really know what could be the cause for this. I've tried multiple inductors, since the original one I had selected had a rather low saturation current. But all of them had the same problem

The inductors I've tried thus far are:

- VLS3010CX-3R3M-1 (3.3uH, Isat 1A, DCR 0.083)(this was the original one, which had a too low saturation current I think)
- IHLP1212BZER3R3M11 (3.3uH, Isat 3.3A, DCR 0.056)
- IHLP1212BZEV3R3MA1 (3.3uH, Isat 4.5A, DCR 0.090)
- 74438336033 (3.3uH, Isat 2.85A, DCR 0.099)

Now I wouldn't really know what could be causing these peaks. At first I thought the saturation current was the issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case. So now I don't really know where these peaks could come from, or what I could do to fix them. If anyone would know what could be the cause of these peaks, or what I could do to prevent them, that would be nice!

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, here's a picture of where I'm measuring.
I also forgot to mention that I adde some dummy load resistors which pull around 200mA, just for testing purposes. My actual load will also be around this much. There's a big ground plane on the bottom layer, and the inductor and output capacitor are connected using big copper planes

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Picture of the top and bottom of the PCB layout, as well as a picture of the scope screen with the ground spring shorted to the probe tip.

[image][image]
[image]

**EDIT 3**

I did some more measuring and found that the peaks were at 500kHz, which is the programmed switching frequency. I assumed one full ripple would be at 500kHz, but it seems I was wrong about that. I also measured across some of the dummy load resistors (Blue waveform) and did indeed find that the peaks were significantly smaller as opposed to measuring on the converter output cap, which makes sense considering Jonathan S.'s answer.

[image]][image]

Comment: Please post pictures of your circuit and probe connections. Did you follow the recommended layout in the datasheet? The loop: C2-U2-L1-C9-C2 must be tight. How are you probing? You can't expect good signal integrity on a circuit like this with a 6 inch scope ground lead.

Comment: @Mattman944 Yes, I followed the recommended layout in the datasheet pretty much exactly. I'm probing with my probe set to 10x and using the little ground spring which attaches to the end of the probe and I'm measuring directly on the output cap, C9

Comment: “Field collapse” is a personal pet peeve of mine. The field does not collapse. U=L*di/dt at all times.

Comment: Is this a 2-layer PCB? Post your layout. Hide the plane.

Comment: Try shorting the scope tip to the ground spring tip and hold up close to the circuit without making contact and tell us what you see.

Comment: added your suggestions to the post, thanks!

Comment: Did you hand-solder the components individually? I see one component appears to be crooked. Also, did you leave the solder flux uncleaned? What flux you used? Note that some flux is slightly conductive. It caused havoc on my 1.2MHz constant current boost converter board.

Comment: @Daan32 **use the same scales** for both images i.e. don't focus differently on the new scope image compared to the original scope image because you cannot make feasible comparisons. And, position the shorted probe very close to where the original probe was placed (within 2 mm). If you wish, the shorted probe can touch one electrode of the capacitor.

Comment: @kaosad I didn't hand solder the components, but I might have accidentally knocked something over whilst changing the inductors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spikes that you're seeing on the scope trace aren't actually present across the 47µF output capacitor. Instead, what's happening here is that the magnetic field produced by the circuit couples into the wire loop formed by the scope tip and its ground spring. This is why you're still seeing it even with the probe tip shorted to ground. It's essentially a (very bad) transformer that lets the scope see some of the voltage across the inductor, as well as the associated switching transients.

**Your circuit is functioning perfectly fine, there's nothing at all wrong with it**. Your PCB layout also looks to be quite good as the input and output current loops are pretty much as small as they can be.

If you want to get rid of the magnetic interference, you could consider wrapping the circuit in an electromagnetic shield, such as mu-metal foil. I doubt that this will be necessary, though.

Comment: That's nice to hear, that does keep me wondering where those peaks originate from though. Is is from the mosfet switching inside the converter itself or something like that?
I also did some further testing, and when I measure across some of the load resistors with some space between them and the converter, the peaks are significantly smaller, but still there. I also found out those peaks are at 500kHz, which is the programmed switching frequency. I thought one full ripple so to speak would be 500kHz, but I was wrong about that (added pics of this to original post)

Comment: @Daan32 Yes, they're from the internal MOSFETs switching. In particular, the rapid change in voltage on the switch node (SW pin) radiates out as electromagnetic interference.